# System.Net.Http: missing from namespace? (using .net 4.5)

Tags: c#, rest, post

TL; DR: I'm new to this language and have no idea what I'm doing

here is my class so far:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;

public class MyClass
    {
        private const string URL = "https://sub.domain.com/objects.json?api_key=123";
        private const string data = @"{""object"":{""name"":""Title""}}";

        public static void CreateObject()
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URL);
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.ContentType = "application/json";
            request.ContentLength = data.Length;
            StreamWriter requestWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream(), System.Text.Encoding.ASCII);
            requestWriter.Write(data);
            requestWriter.Close();

            try
            {
                // get the response
                WebResponse webResponse = request.GetResponse();
                Stream webStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream();
                StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(webStream);
                string response = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
                responseReader.Close();
            }
            catch (WebException we)
            {
                string webExceptionMessage = we.Message;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // no need to do anything special here....
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MyClass.CreateObject();
        }
}
```

when I do csc filename.cs, I get the following error:

> The type or namespace name 'Http' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Net' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Comment: You're trying to access a non-static field from a static method (the `webClient` field). Also, you never actually use it for anything. You could probably just remove it.

Answer (score 132, accepted):

[`HttpClient`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.110).aspx) lives in the [`System.Net.Http`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http(v=vs.110).aspx) namespace.

You'll need to add:

```
using System.Net.Http;
```

And make sure you are referencing `System.Net.Http.dll` in .NET 4.5.

---

The code posted doesn't appear to do anything with `webClient`. Is there something wrong with the code that is actually compiling using `HttpWebRequest`?

---

**Update**

To open the *Add Reference* dialog right-click on your project in *Solution Explorer* and select *Add Reference...*. It should look something like:

[image]

Comment: I just installed .NET 4.5, and it says namespace name 'Http' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Net'

Comment: Are you sure your project is targeting .NET 4.5 and that you've added the reference to `System.Net.Http.dll`?

Comment: I'm not sure, it's just one .cs file. =\ So... do I still need to add a reference to that file? Shouldn't it just auto pick the latest?

Comment: Um... no it won't. Right click on your project in _Solution Explorer_ and click `Add References` when the dialog appears, select the left most tab (I don't use the built-in references dialog but mine is called _Assemblies_). Scroll the list until you see an item called `System.Net.Http` double-click it and rebuild.

Comment: Updated answer to include directions to open the _Add Reference..._ dialog.

Comment: ok, i've gotten to that menu only to realize visual studio is still using .net 4.0. is changing it to 4.5 straightforward?

Comment: Certainly. [Here's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398202.aspx) some documentation from MSDN for doing it. Let me know if you run into any troubles.

Comment: Shouldnøt it be System.Web.Http instead of System.Net.Http?

Comment: Are you working in a solution with multiple projects? Are you sure that the System.Net.Http assembly is installed in the project which contains the file you're looking at? You can adjust which projects load which nuget packages in the Package Manager

Answer (score 107):

NuGet > Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client package

Comment: This pretty much solved the problem for me. I installed this package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.SelfHost/5.2.2

Comment: The accepted answer (adding a reference) didn't help me but this did. Thanks.

Comment: This is the correct approach to take.  Adding a reference to a dll could pose issues on a build server.  Having the correct nuget package will solve the issue.

Answer (score 18):

How I solved it.

1. Open project (!) "Properties", choose "Application", select targeting framework ".Net Framework 4.5"
2. Right click on your project -> Add reference
3. Make sure that in "Assemblies" -> "Extensions" option "System.Net.Http" is unchecked
4. Go to "Assemblies" -> "Framework" and select "System.Net.Http" and "System.Net.Http" options
5. That`s all!

In my case i had at the beginning .Net 4.0 and "Assemblies" -> "Extensions" option "System.Net.Http" with version 2.0.0.0. After my actions "Assemblies" -> "Framework" options "System.Net.Http" and "System.Net.Http" had the same 4.0.0.0 version.

Comment: that was the problem for me as well, it was not showing Reference "System.Net.Http" until I upgraded from .NET 3.5 to .NET 4.5

Answer (score 11):

Visual Studio Package Manager Console > Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client

Answer (score 6):

Assuming that your using Visual Studio 10, you can download an install that includes System.Net.Http, for Visual Studio 10 here:  [download MVC4 for VS10](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30683)

Once you've installed it, right click on the *References* folder in the VS Project and then select *Add Reference*.
Then, select the *Browse* tab. Navigate to the *assemblies* install path for the MVC4 install (usually in Program Files(x86)/Microsoft ASP.NET/ASP.NET MVC4/assemblies) and select the assembly named 'System.Net.Http.dll'.
Now you can add your 'using System.Net.Http' at the top of your code and begin creating HttpClient connections.

Answer (score 6):

just go to add reference then add

```
system.net.http
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I had this issue after upgrading to .NET Framework 4.7.2. I found out that Nuget package for System.Net.Http is no longer recommended. Here are workarounds:

- [Single-name references are removed by the SDK](https://github.com/Microsoft/dotnet/blob/master/releases/net472/KnownIssues/613745%20-%20Single-name%20references%20are%20removed%20by%20the%20SDK%20when%20targeting%204.7.2.md)
- [Nuget package for System.Net.Http on .NET Framework 4.7.2 and newer versions](https://port135.com/2020/08/01/nuget-package-system-net-http-framework/)

Answer (score 3):

You'll need a `using System.Net.Http` at the top.

Answer (score 3):

You need to have a Reference to the `System.Web.Http` assembly which has the `HTTPClient` class, your trying to use. Try adding the below line before your class declaration

```
using System.Web.Http;
```

If you still get the Error, try doing this in `Visual Studio`

1. Right click on the References folder on your project.
2. Select Add Reference.
3. Select the .NET tab (or select the Browse button if it is not a .NET Framework assembly).
4. Double-click the assembly containing the namespace in the error message (`System.Web.Http.dll`).
5. Press the OK button.

Comment: @TheLindyHop: can you try following the steps in the updated answer?

Comment: @Akhil - `HttpClient` belongs to the `System.Web.Http.dll` .NET 4.5 assembly (not `System.Net`).

Comment: How do I get the references folder to show up? I've started with just a file: outside of any project =\

Comment: ok, right Click on your Project, and select `Properties`. You should see `References` on the left hand side.

Comment: @TheLindyHop - Follow the directions in [my comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9611316/system-net-http-missing-from-namespace-using-net-4-5/9611353#comment12195418_9611353). It is similar but slightly more detailed.

Answer (score 3):

For me, it was getting the nuget package Microsoft.Net.Http
.(https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bclteam/p/httpclient/)

Answer (score 2):

[HttpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is new in .net 4.5.  You should probably be using [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx).

Comment: The code included in the question already uses `HttpWebRequest`, not sure why they aren't using it though.

Comment: Agreed. The HTTPClient is being declared, but never being used.  Very odd.

Comment: I'me having an issue including the namespace for it. using System.Net.Http; yeilds the error 'Http' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Net'

Comment: Are you sure you're using the .Net 4.5 compiler?

Answer (score 2):

With the Nuget Package Manager install Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core.

After this:

```
using System.Web.Http;
```

or if you use VB

`imports System.Web.Http`

Answer (score 0):

To solve the problem :

1. Go to your solution explorer.
2. Right click on the project name and choose add
3. Select references and allow the .`Net framework 4.5` to finish loading
4. Scroll down and select `System.Net.Http` and click ok.

*Problem solved.*

Answer (score 0):

Making the "Copy Local" property True for the reference did it for me. Expand References, right-click on System.Net.Http and change the value of Copy Local property to True in the properties window. I'm using VS2019.

Answer (score 0):

See [CS0234 'Http' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Net' when targeting .NET Fx 4.x with implicit usings](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/24146).

I fixed it by installing the nuget package "System.Net.Http"

Answer (score -1):

In Visual Studio you can use nuget to load the package

```
Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost
```