# System.Web.Http is missing after a .NET 4.5 upgrade

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, .net-4.5

I've just upgraded my solution to .NETE 4.5 using [Target Framework Migrator](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/47bded90-80d8-42af-bc35-4736fdd8cd13), and then the package manager console command:

`Update-Package -Reinstall -IgnoreDependencies`

In one of my projects I am using:

```
using System.Web.Http.Controllers;
using System.Web.Http.Filters;
```

The code uses `HttpActionContext` and `ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor`. I notice that `System.Web.Http` has been removed from my references, and is no longer available in the Add New Reference window. What's going on?

Comment: Hi, this should help...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9611316/system-net-http-missing-from-namespace-using-net-4-5
O

Comment: @ojf already saw that question - doesn't help

Comment: are you targeting the 4.5 Client Profile instead of the full framework maybe?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Look in the Extensions part of the "Add new reference", instead of Framework.

If it's not there, it's in the Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core package on NuGet.

Comment: Yes, I see that it's  under Extensions now.

Comment: No. It isn't. Microsoft Visual Studio likes to move things around so much it might have been there at some point. It no longer is.

Answer (score 33):

As for Visual Studio 2017, as said in the [ASP.NET forums](https://forums.asp.net/t/2096814.aspx?Where%20do%20I%20find%20system%20web%20Http), Microsoft has moved the namespace to a NuGet package called [Web API Core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core/).

In order to install it, you need to type`Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core` in the NuGet Package Manager Console.

Comment: Just for everybody information, it works also with VS2015. Thanks!

Comment: This fixed my build with a new machine and VS 2019

Answer (score 2):

Just run the following NuGet command:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me too.
This added `System.Web.Http` version 5.2.7.0 to my App.config file.

Answer (score 1):

I did this:

```
Update-Package -Reinstall
```

And it helped my project be well done.