# Retrieve JSON object and file in MVC

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc

I have the following client-side code to send a JSON object and a file to MVC using JQuery ajax:

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('logo', logoImg);
var objArr = [];

objArr.push({"id": id, "name": userName});

//JSON obj
formData.append('ocorrencia', JSON.stringify( objArr ));


$.ajax({
    url: "/Ocorrencia/Edit",
    type:"POST",
    processData:false,
    contentType: false,
    data: formData,
        complete: function(data){
                    alert("success");
            }
  });
```

On the server-side, I'm using ASP.NET MVC.

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Edit()
{
    // How to retrieve the data and the file here?
```

I have a model to the "ocorrencia". What do I have to do to retrive the model and the file on the server side?

Comment: You could try adding `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.MediaTypeMappings.Add(new RequestHeaderMapping("Accept", "text/html", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase, true, "application/json"));` to the _Register_ method of _WebApiConfig.cs_

Comment: @schlonzo , what does it do?

Comment: @Taian is my answer the correct one? :)

Answer (score 1):

Try using `FromBodyAttribute`

```
using System.Web.Http;
```

```
public JsonResult Edit([FromBody]List<Ocorrencia> ocorrencia,HttpPostedFileBase logo)
{
}
```

**Edited**

`using System.Web.Http` can be added by Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core package on NuGet.

Comment: I'm having the error "The type or namespace 'FromBody' could not be found". =(

Comment: @Taian you have to use `using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;`

Comment: I'm not using AspNetCore, I'm just using AspNet.

Comment: so use `using System.Web.Http; ` :)

Comment: There's no System.Web.Http there too =(

Comment: @Taian, which version of framework are you using? I think you can install Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core package on NuGet. give a look --> [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27819109/system-web-http-missing-after-net-4-5-upgrade)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to correctly define the Action signature on your controller and use Newton Json. Like:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Edit(List<Ocorrencia> ocorrencia)
{
  var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Ocorrencia>>(ocorrencia);
   ...
```

Above code assumes that you have a class named `Ocorrencia`.

Answer (score 0):

You can get both your logo file and your data

```
public JsonResult Edit(List<Ocorrencia> ocorrencia,HttpPostedFileBase logoImg)
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Im going to say that your ajax is wrong, your midding content and dataType

This is an example of what I am using right now and works perfectly

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        headers: { "RequestVerificationToken": $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val() },
        url: url,
        data: JSON.stringify(model),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) {
            ... success code here
        },
            error: function (x, y, z) {
            }
        });
```

I define my model like

```
var model = {
             myObject: "somevalue"
             myOtherObject: 2
             }
```

Url is obvious

and then

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("sign")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Sign([FromBody]ReportLessonSign model)
{
 // your code in here
}
```

At this point the json object is passed into my model and handled accordingly.

With regards to your file, how are you trying to pass this up?

Comment: When I define the `dataType`, I cannot send the file. The `dataType` must be set to `false`.