# Error in sending HTTP requests in Windows Phone 7.1

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, windows-phone, windows-phone-7.1

I am trying to send a HTTP request in Windows Phone using Visual Studio 2010 Express, but I am getting this error:

> The type or namespace name 'HttpClient' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

It's not able to find HttpClient even when I used `using system.windows.httpclient`. I am not able to get which reference is actually missing.

What reference do I need to add? Or what do I need to do to resolve this issue?

Comment: check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9611316/system-net-http-missing-from-namespace-using-net-4-5)

Comment: but d main prob is m nt able to add reference System.Net.Http.dll and so its not able to find http

Comment: what version of .NET Framework you are using? you may want to add this assembly using [NuGet package manager](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Net.Http/)

Comment: .NET Framework 4.5 ..and am unable to add using NuGET package manager as der is no option seen in visual studio 2010 express for windows phone..so is der any othr way to add System.Net.Http.dll ??

Comment: Not possible! You **must** use Visual Studio 2012 in order to utilize .NET 4.5.

Comment: ohkk ..means i need to use Visual studio 2012 for .NET4.5 but still is der any way to upgrade  Visual studio  2010 ?

Comment: No, at least not that i know of

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options here.

1. You must use Visual Studio 2012 or superior.
2. Replace your HttpClient class with [WebClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(v=vs.100).aspx) or [HttpWebRequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest(v=vs.100).aspx).

You cannot use HttpClient with Visual Studio 2010, no Framework 4.5 supported.