# System Namespace not found

Tags: visual-studio, c#-4.0, windows-phone

I am using `using System.Net.Http` , It shows

> error missing directive or dll

How can I fix in visual studio 2015 Community Edition? Its an universal windows phone project.

Actually I am creating the Universal Windows application.

Comment: You need to add a reference to the appropriate assembly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [System.Net.Http: missing from namespace? (using .net 4.5)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9611316/system-net-http-missing-from-namespace-using-net-4-5)