# How can I compile cs file with reference System.Net.Http using csc?

Tags: c#, csc, system.net.httpwebrequest

I am new in C#, and I have spent the entire night just trying to compile my code. I am not asking for a logic, but rather some help with compiling using `csc`.

I have an app that uses `System.Net.Http`, and I am trying to get it compiled into an executable using csc, but I always get the following result:

```
C:\Users\farao\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\source\repos\SimpleWebCrawlerApp\SimpleWebCrawlerApp>csc Program.cs
Microsoft (R) Visual C# Compiler version 2.6.0.62329 (5429b35d)
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Program.cs(4,18): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Http' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Net' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

C:\Users\farao\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\source\repos\SimpleWebCrawlerApp\SimpleWebCrawlerApp>
```

However, I can compile in Visual Studio 2017, but I do need to compile it using `csc` for quick distribution.

I tried almost everything from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9611316/system-net-http-missing-from-namespace-using-net-4-5)

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Collections;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace SimpleWebCrawlerApp
{

class Program
{
    internal static int SUCCESS = 0;
    internal static int FAIL = -1;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TextWriter errorWriter = Console.Error;
        if (args.Length != 2)
        {
            errorWriter.WriteLine("usage: <program_name>.exe <http/https url> <number of hops>");
        }
        else
        {
            if (IsValidUrl(args[0]))
            {
                int hops;
                if (int.TryParse(args[1], out hops))
                {
                    new HTTPCrawler(args[0], hops).Crawl();
                    Environment.Exit(SUCCESS);
                }
                errorWriter.WriteLine("not a valid integer for number of hops");
            }
            else
            {
                errorWriter.WriteLine("observe proper http/https protocol");
            }
        }
        Environment.Exit(FAIL);
    }
```

Comment: *"I do need to compile it using `csc` for quick distribution."* that sounds wrong. There's no difference between compiling from within Visual Studio and from command line that would make distribution any faster. Further you could also use `msbuild` to build the project directly (which includes the correct assembly references)

Comment: Also if you read the documentation for `csc` you'll find options like `/reference` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/reference-compiler-option) which you need to add to your command line (as your error message tells you)

Comment: I am not a C# developer, but your comment led me to the solution. Thank you! ``csc /r:System.Net.Http.dll Program.cs``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem thanks to UnholySheep.

`csc /r:System.Net.Http.dll Program.cs`

References:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/reference-compiler-option

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.118).aspx