# How to call two or more web services or REST in parallel with Project Reactor and join the answers

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, project-reactor

Hello I would like to know how to call two or more web services or Rest services in pararelo and compose a response of the calls.

I have found some examples on the web using other technologies but I can not get it to work with a reactor

```
// start task A asynchronously
CompletableFuture<ResponseA> futureA = asyncServiceA.someMethod(someParam);
// start task B asynchronously
CompletableFuture<ResponseB> futureB = asyncServiceB.someMethod(someParam);

CompletableFuture<String> combinedFuture = futureA
        .thenCombine(futureB, (a, b) -> a.toString() + b.toString());

// wait till both A and B complete
String finalValue = combinedFuture.join();
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
static void Run()
{
    //Follow steps at this link for addding a reference to the necessary .NET library:
    //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9611316/system-net-http-missing-from-    
    //namespace-using-net-4-5

    //Create an HTTP Client
    var client = new HttpClient();

    //Call first service
    var task1 = client.GetAsync("http://www.cnn.com");

    //Call second service
    var task2 = client.GetAsync("http://www.google.com");

    //Create list of all returned async tasks
    var allTasks = new List<Task<HttpResponseMessage>> { task1, task2 };

    //Wait for all calls to return before proceeding
    Task.WaitAll(allTasks.ToArray());

}
```

Answer (score 7):

Let's imagine you need to hit 2 services, so you nee 2 base `WebClient` (each is configured with the correct base URL and eg. an authentication scheme):

```
@Bean
public WebClient serviceAClient(String authToken) {
    return WebClient.builder()
            .baseUrl("http://serviceA.com/api/v2/")
            .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "Basic " + authToken)
            .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
            .build();
}

@Bean
public WebClient serviceBClient(String authToken): WebClient {
    return WebClient.builder()
            .baseUrl("https://api.serviceB.com/")
            .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "token " + authToken)
            .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
            .build();
}
```

From there, let's assume you get these 2 webclients injected in your controller (as *qualified* beans). Here's the code to make a joint call to both using Reactor:

```
Mono<ResponseA> respA = webclientA.get()
                                 .uri("/sub/path/" + foo)
                                 .retrieve()
                                 .bodyToMono(ResponseA.class);
Mono<ResponseB> respB = webclientB.get()
                                 .uri("/path/for/b")
                                 .retrieve()
                                 .bodyToMono(ResponseB.class);
Mono<String> join = respA.zipWith(respB, (a, b) -> a.toString + b.toString);
return join;
```

Note the zip function could produce something more meaningful like a business object out of the 2 responses. The resulting `Mono<String>` only triggers the 2 requests if something subscribes to it (in the case of Spring WebFlux, the framework will do that if you return it from a controller method).

Comment: If code has more(40) WebClient with different base path, Do we need to create it by using @Bean each and every-time? Since it will be too much to write that code.

Comment: not necessarily, the `baseUri` can be overridden on `get` calls by providing an absolute URI (see [builder's doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/reactive/function/client/WebClient.Builder.html#baseUrl-java.lang.String-))

Answer (score 4):

If you´re using Spring reactor what you need is the operator Zip, to run your process and zip them once are finished.

```
/**
 * Zip operator execute the N number of Flux independently, and once all them are finished, results
 * are combined in TupleN object.
 */
@Test
public void zip() {
    Flux<String> flux1 = Flux.just("hello ");
    Flux<String> flux2 = Flux.just("reactive");
    Flux<String> flux3 = Flux.just(" world");
    Flux.zip(flux1, flux2, flux3)
            .map(tuple3 -> tuple3.getT1().concat(tuple3.getT2()).concat(tuple3.getT3()))
            .map(String::toUpperCase)
            .subscribe(value -> System.out.println("zip result:" + value));
}
```

You can see more about reactive technology here https://github.com/politrons/reactive

Comment: What if the number of flux objects are dynamic? Is there a way to send n number of arguments  to the zip method?

Answer (score 2):

If you already have a synchronous implementation you can easily add some reactor features to make it run in parallel thanks to `Mono.fromCallable()` method.

```
Mono<ResponseA> responseA = Mono
.fromCallable(() -> blockingserviceA.getResponseA())
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.elastic()); // will execute on a separate thread when called
Mono<ResponseB> responseB = Mono
.fromCallable(() -> blockingserviceB.getResponseB())
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.elastic());
// At that point nothing has been called yet, responseA and responseB are empty Mono

AggregatedStuff aggregatedStuff = Mono.zip(responseA, responseB) // zip as many Mono as you want
.flatMap(r -> doStuff(r.getT1(), r.getT2())) // do whatever needed with the results
.block(); // execute the async calls, and then execute flatMap transformation
```

The important thing to note between `fromCallable()` and `just()`, is that `just()` will execute directly and in the main thread, but `fromCallable()` is **lazy** meaning it will only be executed when needed, e.g: when you call block(), collect() (for Flux), ...etc...

```
Mono<ResponseA> responseA = Mono
.just(blockingserviceA.getResponseA()) // execute directly
Mono<ResponseB> responseB = Mono
.just(blockingserviceB.getResponseB()) // execute directly
// Above code have been executed sequentially, you can access response result 
// => yes it is kind of useless, and yes it is exactly how I did it the first time!
```

So avoid to use `just()` for heavy tasks that you want to run in parallel. Using `just()` for instantiation is completely correct since you would not want to create a new thread, and get the overhead that comes with it, every time you instantiate a String or any other object.

PS: As Simon Baslé pointed out you can use WebClient to directly return Mono and Flux and do async calls, but if you already have your api clients implemented and don't have the option of refactoring the entire application, `fromCallable()` is a simple way to setup asynchronous process without refactoring to much code.