# System.Net.Http Unavailable for .Net 4.5 Application. Reference Has Been Added

Tags: c#, .net, http, .net-4.5

I have a .Net 4.5 application. It has a reference added to System.Net.Http, but when I add the line

```
using System.Net.Http;
```

I get the error:
Error   CS0234  The type or namespace name 'Http' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Net' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

The assembly reference is there for System.Net.Http v4.0.30319.

I've tried adding the Nuget package for System.Net.Http v4.3.3 and still the same thing.

Http shows in my list as unavailable.

[image]

Little help?
Thanks.

Comment: open the output window, select "package manager" from the combobox and see if the package manager has logged anything useful about the installation of the v4.3.3 package.

Comment: Did this post help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9611316/system-net-http-missing-from-namespace-using-net-4-5?rq=1

Comment: No errors are shown for the Nuget package. The link just says make sure a reference is added and it is definitely added.

Comment: Are you sure the project in question is targeting .NET 4.5 or above?

Comment: Yes, the target framework for the project is .Net Framework 4.5

Comment: The tooltip indicates a multi targeting project (instead of a .NET Framework 4.5 project). So what's been hidden by you?

Comment: It says the same project name twice, but one says available and one says not available. I'm not sure why. I just thought it proper to hide the company name. So it says  'company.service.relay - available' and 'company.service.relay - not available'. Could that be the problem?

Comment: The file that this is happening to is in the App_Code folder. If I add System.Net.Http anywhere else in the project (the contollers) it works fine...