# API linking Database to MVC project and Mobile App Xamarin

Tags: api, azure, model-view-controller, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

I'm new to Xamarin,  I'm using VS 2017 Enterprise with the latest Xamarin updates.

I want to add an API so that the Db can communicate with both my mobile app and MVC project.

I created a cross-platform blank, .NET Standard project.

I added a new folder to the solution and within that folder a class to write my RestAPI code.

When writing the code I used HttpClient but it gives me an error asking if I'm

> missing an assembly or reference.

How can I write code for my REstApi if I can't use HttpClient?

OR is there a better way to allow my Db to communicate with both my MVC project and mobile app?

I will publish both my MVC project and mobile app on Azure. Thanks

Comment: I would suggest you don't directly link the mobile app with the database but rather create a REST Web-API and then use that for DB connection, And yes you can use HTTPClient in xamarin

Answer (score 0):

**Firstly**

For the error that appears:  `missing an assembly or reference.`

The HttpClient lives in the "System.Net.Http" namespace.

You'll need to add: `using System.Net.Http;`

as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9611316/system-net-http-missing-from-namespace-using-net-4-5)

---

**secondly**

is there a better way to allow your Db to communicate with both your **MVC project** and **mobile app**?

**yes** there is better way,after publish your MVC Project,

you can use **Azure Mobile Client**.

- **step 1**

Open "Package Manager Console" and type

> Install-Package Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client -Version 4.0.2

or you can get the last version from [Azure Mobile Client SDK](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client/)

> This library provides features for creating Windows and Xamarin mobile apps that connect to Azure Mobile Apps

- **step 2**

assume you have a class called "user",
and you want to read,  insert, update and delete data

take a look at the following code example:

> ```
> using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices;
> using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
> using System.Threading.Tasks;
>
>  public class User {/*....*/ }
>
>
>   public class AzureServices
>   {
>       private static readonly string url = "http://xxxxx.azurewebsites.net";
>
>       /*
>        * The Azure Mobile Client SDK provides the MobileServiceClient class, 
>        * which is used by a Xamarin.Forms application to access the Azure Mobile Apps instance
>       */
>
>       public MobileServiceClient Client;
>       public IMobileServiceTable<User> UserTable;
>
>       public AzureServices()
>       {
>           /* 
>            * When the MobileServiceClient instance is created,
>            * an application URL must be specified to identify the Azure Mobile Apps instance.
>           */
>
>           Client = new MobileServiceClient(url);
>
>           //calling the GetTable method on the MobileServiceClient instance, which returns a IMobileServiceTable<User> reference.
>           UserTable = Client.GetTable<User>();
>       }
>
>       // Querying Data
>       public async Task<ObservableCollection<User>> GetAllUsers(bool sync = false)
>       {
>           var userList = await UserTable.ToEnumerableAsync();
>           return new ObservableCollection<User>(userList);
>       }
>       //Inserting Data
>       public async Task AddUser(User item)
>       {
>           await UserTable.InsertAsync(item);
>       }
>       // Updating Data
>       public async Task UpdateUser(User item)
>       {
>           await UserTable.UpdateAsync(item);
>       }
>       // Deleting Data
>       public async Task DeleteUser(User item)
>       {
>           await UserTable.DeleteAsync(item);
>       }
>
>   }
> ```

For more information visit [Azure Mobile App](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/consuming/azure)